# Azure Function throws SimpleInjector.ActivationException in "stress test"

Tags: azure-functions, simple-injector

We have a couple of functions in a function app based on a consumption plan. When I stress test these functions with JMeter (200 threads simultaneously), the functions are throwing SimpleInjector.ActivationException's for about 50% of the time. Not all requests are failing.

I don't get why this is only for a part of the requests.

Call stack:

2021-07-06T08:43:41.159 [Error] Er is een probleem opgetreden

SimpleInjector.ActivationException : The constructor of type GetLocalKeyDataByDateQueryHandler contains the parameter with name 'queryValidator' and type IValidator, but IValidator is not registered. For IValidator to be resolved, it must be registered in the container.at SimpleInjector.Container.ThrowParameterTypeMustBeRegistered(InjectionTargetInfo target)at SimpleInjector.Advanced.DefaultDependencyInjectionBehavior.GetInstanceProducer(InjectionConsumerInfo dependency,Boolean throwOnFailure)at SimpleInjector.ContainerOptions.GetInstanceProducerFor(InjectionConsumerInfo consumer)at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildConstructorParameters(ConstructorInfo constructor)at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildNewExpression()at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildTransientExpression()at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildTransientDelegate()at SimpleInjector.Lifestyles.ScopedRegistration.BuildExpression()at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildExpressionInternal()at SimpleInjector.Internals.LazyEx`1.InitializeAndReturn()at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildInstanceCreator()at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildAndReplaceInstanceCreatorAndCreateFirstInstance()at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.GetInstance()at SimpleInjector.Container.GetInstanceTServiceat async ProRail.PUIC2.Web.Functions.GetPuicDataByChangeDate.Run(GetPuicDataByDate inputParams,ILogger logger,ExecutionContext context) at D:\a\1\s\Src\Web\ProRail.PUIC2.Web.Functions\Functions\GetPuicDataByChangeDate.cs : 35

Function:

```cs
    public class GetPuicDataByLocalKey
    {
        [FunctionName("GetPuicDataByLocalKey")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)]
            Models.GetPuicDataByLocalKey queryInput, ILogger logger, ExecutionContext context)
        {
            var container = DependencyInjection.GetContainerInstance(context);

            await using (AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(container))
            {
                var loggingUtils = container.GetInstance<ILoggingUtils>();
                try
                {
                    logger.LogTrace(loggingUtils.MethodBegin);

                    container.GetInstance<Configuration.ILoggerFactory>().SetLogger(logger);
                    var queryHandler = container.GetInstance<IQueryHandler<GetPuicDataQuery, IEnumerable<PuicData>>>();
                    var results = await queryHandler.Handle(new GetPuicDataQuery
                    {
                        Source = queryInput.Source,
                        DateValid = queryInput.DateValid,
                        LocalKeyValues = queryInput.LocalKeyValues.Select(lkv => new Core.Entities.Data.KeyValue
                        {
                            Key = lkv.Key,
                            Value = lkv.Value
                        })
                    });

                    if (results == null)
                    {
                        return new JsonResult(Enumerable.Empty<Models.PuicData>());
                    }

                    // Get local keys grouped by Puic
                    var puicDataList = results.GroupBy(l => l.Puic).Select(g => PuicDataConverter.Convert(g));

                    return new JsonResult(puicDataList);
                }
                catch (PuicException e)
                {
                    logger.LogError(e, "Data is waarschijnlijk niet goed");
                    return new BadRequestErrorMessageResult(e.Message);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    logger.LogError(e, "Er is een probleem opgetreden");
                    return new InternalServerErrorResult();
                }
                finally
                {
                    logger.LogTrace(loggingUtils.MethodEnd);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Container config

```cs
    public static class DependencyInjection
    {
        private static Container containerInstance = null;

        public static Container GetContainerInstance(ExecutionContext context)
        {
            if (containerInstance == null)
            {
                containerInstance = new Container();
                containerInstance.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();

                InitializeConfiguration(containerInstance, context);
                RegisterSimpleTypes(containerInstance);
                RegisterQueryHandlers(containerInstance);
                RegisterCommandHandlers(containerInstance);
                RegisterValidators(containerInstance);
                RegisterDatabaseTypes(containerInstance);
            }

            return containerInstance;
        }

[...]

        private static void RegisterQueryHandlers(Container container)
        {
            var businessLogicAssembly = typeof(GetUsersQuery).Assembly;
            container.Register(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>), businessLogicAssembly, Lifestyle.Scoped);
        }

[...]

    }
```

Comment: Hi Cees, you only posted an exception message and stack trace. This, unfortunately, isn't enough for the problem to be reproduced. In order to get satisfying answers, you'll have to provide more information. Can you transform your question into a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Hi Steven, yess I will try to complement my description.

Comment: Hi @Steven, is the addition of code sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a multi-threading issue with your code; the `DependencyInjection.GetContainerInstance` method.

`GetContainerInstance` possibly creates many `Container` instances when called in parallel and the configuration of the final `Container` instance will be undetermined.

To fix this issue, you will have to synchronize the creation of the container. There are many ways to do this, but you can, for instance, try this:

```cs
public static Container GetContainerInstance(ExecutionContext context)
{
    // Double-checked lock. Ensures only one Container instance
    // is created.
    if (containerInstance is null)
    {
        lock (typeof(DependencyInjection))
        {
            if (containerInstance is null)
            {
                containerInstance = BuildContainer();
            }
        }
    }

    return containerInstance;
}

private static Container BuildContainer()
{
    var container = new Container();
    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle =
        new AsyncScopedLifestyle();

    InitializeConfiguration(container, context);
    RegisterSimpleTypes(container);
    RegisterQueryHandlers(container);
    RegisterCommandHandlers(container);
    RegisterValidators(container);
    RegisterDatabaseTypes(container);

    return container;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I will try this and come back to report.

Comment: Yesss it almost worked =] I assigned the container to the containerInstance after the RegisterDatabaseTypes() because it still happened :). If you could introduce a local variable at the line where you create the new Container() instance, I will mark it as the right answer :)